# It could be possible to create an email addon to convert an email address in a generic soap client?

Tags: soap, client, email, generic-handler

What i mean?
Imagine:

```
From:me@mydomain.com
To:webservice_client@gmail.com
Subject:Our_wsdl_file_here
Body:Soap Body Here
```

And receive response to my email.

It could be possible to create an addon to gmail or something like that to do that?

Edit:
Firefox has a simple - i think addon https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/soa-client/ to make a soap generic client, it could be modified to do what i suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOAP over email has been standardised.

- http://www.w3.org/TR/soap12-email
- http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/WD-soap12-part0-20011217/#SMTP

So yes, it is possible.